# How do I write migrate group files?

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm trying to create a Migrate group with following code. But it is not detected & listed in admin/structure/migrate. Both migrate plus & Migrate tools modules are installed.  I"m trying to create migration from WordPress tables. The module is called migrate_wordpress & migrate group is defined in config/install with the name migrate_wordpress. migrate_group.wordpress.yml

```
id: wprdpress
label: WordPress Imports
description: Import from WordPress blog
source_type: Custom tables
```

What is wrong with above Migrate group configurations? What is the correct way to write an migrate group configuration file in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that groups are a feature of the migrate_plus module. In order for them to be recognised, the file needs to be named `migrate_plus.migration_group.<group_name>.yml`. The actual migrations also need to be formatted like this `migrate_plus.migration.<migration_name>.yml`.

One other issue I see is that your `id: wprdpress` should be `id: wordpress`. (Just in case that typo is in your code :) )

The last thing is that migrations are only defined on module install. This means that you have to uninstall and re-install every time. (Or you can implement some drush commands to do it for you. Check out [this tutorial](http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/registering-migrations-drupal-8).)

Comment: It worked wonderful , I'm able to see Migration groups and actual migrations listed too.  Also thanks for the nice tutorial.

Comment: Glad it helped! This is all fresh in my brain as I've been working my way through my own D8 migration. Banged my head against the wall for quite a while on this one.

Comment: The [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module has the command `drush dre my_module` to reinstall a module.

Answer (score 1):

In .yml file we define four major parts for Migration. These are *id, source, process and destination*. Id is to identify this Migration process Id to identify. Source is defined with the data source. Process define basically the mapping of fields in between destination and source.
It seems you are missing process and destination.
To define Migration group you can define it like this

*migration_group: custom 

destination:
  
    plugin: entity:file*

You can refer this [Migrate Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate) as well.